# Why does my in-wheel BLDC motor have sinusoidal back emf (line to line) when rotated by external system?

Tags: electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor, electric-machine, magnetic-flux

I have an in-wheel BLDC motor with 46 poles (permanent magnet) on the rotor and 51 slots in the stator. When I used an external machine to rotate my in-wheel BLDC motor, then measuring across two phase back EMF I got sinusoidal back EMF instead of trapezoidal.

Can any one explain why this happened?

[image]

For the measurement of back EMF constant, how one can calculate if back EMF is sinusoidal?

Answer (score 2):

You are measuring the line-line voltage and not the phase voltage.

The characteristic "trapezoidal" backEMF is only present at the phase voltage. When you view this line-line the waveform appears like a pointy sinewave. Then there are specifics of the build: magnet span, width of stator tooth foot... all these things influence the shape of the backEMF.  With a high polecount the arc needed for a magnetic gap will be very small and probably non-existent.

[image]

And thus the line-line at the terminals would appear:

[image]

in practice you won't see this and it will naturally be rounder as this is the mathematical concise result. The point still stands. Line-Line is more sinus than most appreciate.

Comment: In this situation how one can find Back EMF constant?

Comment: you make a distinction between phase voltage and line-line voltage, I think you perhaps mean phase-neutral voltage vs phase-phase voltage? any how if the phase-phase voltage is sinusoidal then the phase-neutral voltage will also be sinusoidal.

Comment: you have drawn the trapezoidal wave form incorrectly, the high or low values are maintained for 120 degrees not 60.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a PMSM and not a BLDC. There is a lot of confusion about how to identify them, but the easiest way is exactly what you did and since you have a Sinusoidal bEMF your motor must be a PMSM.

In this [link](https://things-in-motion.blogspot.com/2018/12/why-most-hobby-grade-bldc-out-runners.html) you will find a nicely elaborated explanation.